# How to solve Not Found (HTTP 404) in package mscstexta4r in R?

Tags: r, azure-cognitive-services, text-analysis

I followed this [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mscstexta4r/mscstexta4r.pdf) to implement a text analysis application using the Microsoft Cognitive Services.

First I created a subscription and got the api keys [here](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/subscriptions). Then I created a new R project. I created a json file named `.mscskeys.json` in my working directory. It contains:

```
{
"textanalyticsurl": "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/texta/analytics/v2.0/",
"textanalyticskey": "--my API key--"
}
```

This the code in my R script.

```
install.packages("mscstexta4r")

library(mscstexta4r)
textaInit()



docsText <- c(
  "Loved the food, service and atmosphere! We'll definitely be back.",
  "Very good food, reasonable prices, excellent service.",
  "It was a great restaurant.",
  "If steak is what you want, this is the place.",
  "The atmosphere is pretty bad but the food is quite good.",
  "The food is quite good but the atmosphere is pretty bad.",
  "The food wasn't very good.",
  "I'm not sure I would come back to this restaurant.",
  "While the food was good the service was a disappointment.",
  "I was very disappointed with both the service and my entree."
)
docsLanguage <- rep("en", length(docsText))

tryCatch({
  textaDetectLanguages('love', numberOfLanguagesToDetect = 1L)
  # Perform sentiment analysis
  textaSentiment(
    documents = docsText,    # Input sentences or documents
    languages = docsLanguage
    # "en"(English, default)|"es"(Spanish)|"fr"(French)|"pt"(Portuguese)
  )

}, error = function(err) {

  # Print error
  geterrmessage()

})
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

> Error: mscstexta4r: Not Found (HTTP 404). - { "statusCode": 404,
>   "message": "Resource not found" }

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because the url need to be "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/"

not "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/texta/analytics/v2.0/"

There isn't lettre "a" behind "text".

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to modify

`https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0`

to

`https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/`

Notice the additional `/` this allows the application to connect to the appropriate service for example

`.../sentiment`